# How do I enable DML logging in Cassandra 2.1?

Tags: cassandra, logging

How to enable logging DML(inserts, updates), DDL (alter, create) operations in cassandra version 2.1?

```
nodetool getlogginglevels

Logger Name                                        Log Level
ROOT                                                    INFO
com.thinkaurelius.thrift                               ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try Ericsson's Cassandra Audit Logger: https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit

I've used it with Cassandra 3.  Not sure if they have a version that works with 2.1.  If they do, you'll need to download the JAR for your version, and put it in your `$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib` dir.

If they don't have one for your version, you can build your own locally (can't remember the process exactly...it's been a few years).  Fork, pull down locally, and check the `pom.xml` file for clues.  Once you build it, put the JAR in your `$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib` dir.

Then edit the end of your cassandra-env.sh file to reference the `AuditQueryHandler` class.

```
JVM_EXTRA_OPTS="$JVM_EXTRA_OPTS -Dcassandra.custom_query_handler_class=com.ericsson.bss.cassandra.ecaudit.handler.AuditQueryHandler"
```

You'll also need to edit the cassandra.yaml, and switch-out the default CassandraRoleManager to use theirs:

```
role_manager: com.ericsson.bss.cassandra.ecaudit.auth.AuditRoleManager
```

Give this repo a look, and see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra has an [Audit Logging](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/auditlogging.html) feature which logs:

- authentication attempts (both successful and failed)
- CQL queries (both successful and failed)

However this feature is not available in older releases of Cassandra and is only available in C* 4.0+ ([CASSANDRA-12151](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12151)).

With Cassandra 2.1 having reached end-of-life in 2021, unfortunately there are no out-of-the-box solutions available to you. Cheers!